# Some pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

If we have such structure(a node of a linked list):

```
    struct Node{
        int data;
        struct Node* next;
    }
```

and we have 2 pointers(a and b), such that

```
a->next = b;
```

how do I swap the two pointers a and b (so that `a->next = b->next` and `b->next = a`)? I tried something like this:

```
  a->next = b->next;
  b->next = a;
```

but it seems not to be working... What is wrong with this code snippet? Does `a->next` end up pointing to itself? By doing this `a->next = b->next` do we make `a->next` point to whatever `b->next` is pointing, or do we make it point to what `b->next` was pointing at the moment of assignment? 
Man, pointers are confusing.. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried the pen&paper approach of inspecting what happens?

Comment: Yes, though it wasn't completely clear to me, because of my last question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visualize what you're trying to do like this:

```
   A           B           C
| data |    | data |    | data |
| next | -> | next | -> | next | -> NULL
```

This is your initial state.  Let's step through your code and see if it results in what you're trying to achieve.  First, you have this:

```
a->next = b->next;
```

After executing this statement, you'll have this:

```
   A           C
| data |    | data |
| next | -> | next | -> NULL

   B           C
| data |    | data |
| next | -> | next | -> NULL
```

The next statement is this:

```
b->next = a;
```

After executing this statement you'll end up with this:

```
   B           A           C
| data |    | data |    | data |
| next | -> | next | -> | next | -> NULL
```

You've achieved your desired outcome.  Your logic is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I assume there are 2 `Node` objects (let me call them `n0` and `n1`) and two variables `a` and `b` that point to `n0` and `n1` respectively. Additionally, each `Node` has its own pointer. That leaves us with 4 pointers initially that look like:

```
a -> n0
b -> n1
n0.next -> n1
n1.next -> ?
```

and here's what happens after these 2 assignments:

```
// a->next = b->next;
a -> n0
b -> n1
n0.next -> ?
n1.next -> ?

// b->next = a;
a -> n0
b -> n1
n0.next -> ?
n1.next -> n0
```

So nothing suspicious so far. As they say, "contradictions don't exist - check your assumptions". So maybe `a` and `b` don't point to the right place initially? There could be only one `Node` and you could have a setup like:

```
a -> n0
b -> n0
n0.next -> n0
```

which still has the property that `a->next == b` as in your question but looks totally different.

Look for the error elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign `a->next = b->next;` you have lost the pointer of `a-next` so what to do is :

```
struct Node * tmp;
tmp = a->next;
a->next = b->next;
b->next = tmp;
```